# Dealing with bad Pluralsight IQ results

Tags: discussion, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

Suppose my internet connection goes down during a Pluralsight test, which is timed, and I get a very bad score. Assume also that I've already used up the 1 free re-try, so the very bad score stands.

Can the Pluralsight result be removed from my profile's developer story?
If so, how?

Is there a way to re-try a test after a reasonable period (say a month?), to try to get a better result?

Comment: You click on the little gear icon which opens a pop up with a delete button, or just don't add it to your dev story in the first place.

Comment: @Tiny Cool. This was more a placeholder post for people wondering about the risk of taking the test and knowing that there's an "undo" button

Comment: This question is about the Pluralsight IQ assessment itself, not the SO integration, thus unrelated. But to answer your Q: No, there's no way to re-take/delete the result. You can only hide it from your PS profile.

Comment: I got a "very high" score, but I have to say that the questions are quite awful and often incorrect (in the JavaScript test). After taking the test I have no intention of advertizing its score.

Comment: I had alot of problems with the test. The level of english language used was way above my non native english tongue.

Comment: Opened a question about it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test?cb=1

Answer (score 26):

Documenting this for posterity:

The PluralsightIQ box has a little gear icon on its top right corner:

[image]

If you hover over it, you'll get a "Delete" option you can use to remove scores you don't want to feature any more:

[image]

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for the cropping - looks much clear now

Answer (score 25):

Use another Pluralsight account and do the test again. When you link the account, it will be automatically added to logged in stackoverflow account..

Comment: This goes to show just how reliable the results are. *You don't like the results, use another account.*

Comment: `Pluralsight IQ test` is a game where you can cheat, it doesn't show the depth of knowledge.

Comment: This is essentially the same solution people use to deal with bad results on Stack Overflow accounts, so I wonder if we might see weird correlations due to people applying the same alt abuse skillset on both sites.

Comment: How 'reliable' can results be where you can't verify the actual person that filled in the answers? About as reliable as anything else anyone can lie about in terms of experience, it's an indicator to ability, and a self-measure for people interested in their actual ability. You wouldn't employ someone claiming to have a degree without an interview, I would think the same applies for this. How often can you retake it though?