# Incorrect questions in Pluralsight IQ test

Tags: discussion, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I just did the Pluralsight IQ test after seeing fellow chat members do it and reading the featured SO statements. The questions in the test I took (was JavaScript) were *awful*, some of them were downright incorrect and most were ambiguous. I think aligning the Stack Overflow brand <sub>(peer reviewed correctness that gets edited when it becomes irrelevant)</sub> with Pluralsight IQ <sub>(full of incorrect questions/answers)</sub> is a bad idea. I had a very negative user experience.

So basically:

- I'd like to see if I'm the only one who had such an experience or if this is commonplace?
- If there is any way that SO can approach Pluralsight directly about it and fix the tests?

Honestly I don't mind my score one bit (it wouldn't matter for job performance or hiring anyway) but I'm very concerned about the negative experience new programmers might have - we do a lot to be nice(ish) in Stack Overflow and I'm very dissatisfied with the user experience.

---

Here are some sample answers from my Pluralsight test, if anyone cares I can add more examples:

[image: "Local scope can be defined within which of the following?" example]

Which is wrong for at least a few years, and has been wrong even before (JavaScript had block scoping before ES2015 with `with` and `try/catch`).

Here is another example where the terminology isn't clear. It's not obvious whether or not `null` is a part of the prototype chain and it's a bad question:

[image: "Based on the following, what is the prototype chain for 'a'?" example]

Formally - null is *not* a part of the prototype chain - quoting the spec:

> Every object created by a constructor has an implicit reference (called the object’s prototype) to the value of its constructor’s “prototype” property. Furthermore, a prototype may have a non-null implicit reference to its prototype, and so on; this is called the prototype chain.

Now, eventually I started to figure out "what they were aiming for" and answered incorrect questions correctly (meaning incorrectly) which I think undermines the whole premise.

Comment: I'm sorry if this comes off as a rant - if there is another way you think I should phrase myself that can cause the issue to be solved more effectively - I'm all ears

Comment: Also, this is explicitly about PluralSight IQ, I am not criticizing pluralsight's courses (which I find excellent usually).

Comment: Question 16 there threw me off, too. Looks like PS doesn't account for `const` / `let` block scoping.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something daft here, but how is this question about Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange?  It looks to me like it's a question about Pluralsight, which would be off-topic on Meta.

Comment: The javascript one is the worst of the 6 I have taken. Felt completely ripped by some of the questions / answers with many feeling like "trick questions" not actual knowledge tests.

Comment: @joec I found out because it’s integrated with StackOverflow, so it is relevant here.

Comment: @JoeC good question - I don't know if you've seen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/add-an-assessment-to-your-developer-story but PluralSight IQ is now directly integrated into StackOverflow (developer story)

Comment: Java had one similarly ambiguously stated question with a wrong answer that can be explained by a misuderstanding of the docs on multithreading... while it's understandable they got the question wrong, the feedback you can give on the questions is terribly annoying to give and hard to follow up on

Comment: These two questions you pointed out got me as well... I picked the exact same answers! I'm also **concerned about re-taking the test again, who knows when they'll change the correct answer?** PS should publish an apology and state that they have removed those two questions from the test.

Comment: ["a single source of truth for measuring skill level"](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/news/pluralsight-iq-assessments) ... yeah right, amateur hour at its finest. It's a shame SO associated itself with such crap.

Comment: Honestly, there are far too many errors in these tests. I learned the quirks and retook them, but more quirks popped up naturally. I'm certainly not paying for something as out of date as this. I flagged nearly half of the questions between HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Presumably they haven't been fixed.

Comment: I would have thought that if you were going to get a bunch of people who answer / review programming questions all day to answer a bunch of "standardized" programming questions in order to judge their skill level, the questions would have been reviewed a little bit better beforehand. ... wait a second. They just enlisted us to review all of _their_ questions as well as ours...

Comment: anecdata: all ~30 questions [I've seen] on Python are *correct* (there were a couple kind of ambiguous questions but it is expected from any such test). The tests may be useful in the same situation a fizz buzz test may be useful: you wouldn't believe how many candidates it can filter. For a complete beginner, it may suggest topics that need to be studied more.

Comment: Stackoverflow to pluralsight: https://xkcd.com/1695/

Comment: This was all part of the *real* test. (And you passed!)

Comment: Oh, so you mean to tell us that the service which claims to assign an accurate knowledge score based on a small questionnaire is crap? Who would have guessed that (/s if you can't tell). Especially because they named themselves after the IQ test, which as everyone knows is... oh yeah, it's crap as well. So, the real question is, why would anybody bother with this BS?

Comment: @l4mpi that's all right - but the question is why StackOverflow is affiliated with it - you can actually tell a lot from the _right_ 40 questions and I don't know if they do proper psychometrics or if they constructed it professionally or not - but the actual questions were bad which is simpler to fix.

Comment: "but the question is why StackOverflow is affiliated with it" - probably because of money. I doubt any competent programmer had much to say in that decision.

Comment: Surprised they still have the question about block vs function scope. I reported it as inaccurate the day SO added the integration which was a couple weeks ago IIRC

Comment: @l4mpi "Especially because they named themselves after the IQ test, which as everyone knows is... oh yeah, it's crap as well." Citation needed. I'm sympathetic to the idea, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: @jpmc26 SO comments are too short to elaborate what exactly is wrong with IQ tests (or rather, with using an IQ test result as basis for anything except as a measure of how well you solve similar tests). For an overview of its problems, see the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#Criticism_and_views

Comment: @l4mpi IQ predicting school performance is a scientific fact as much as anything can be, if you're going to deny that just go all in and claim the earth is flat and the world is ruled by reptilians. The criticism comes mostly from humanitarian racists who always assume science is wrong when they don't like the outcome.

Comment: @Oleg no idea what this has to do with racism, or "school performance" (let's not open that can of worms but doing well in school is not neccessarily related to ones abilities; I know at least two people with a CS masters degree who would struggle with coding hello world). Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my previous comment, but the main problem I see with IQ is the test results being misused to construct assertions about things which have little relation to the original test; e.g. a high IQ does not imply the person has high programming skill (and the same is true for the pluralsight score)

Comment: Oh look, Brainbench is back.

Comment: Possibly related: [Pluralsight IQ credibility and quality/relevance of their tests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363279)

Comment: I was absolutely offended by the pluralsight exam for C#.  Some of the questions were so ambiguous that there were multiple possible answers.  I quit the exam after three or four questions because I didn't want the black mark on my profile.  I've been doing C# programming for 10 years as professional and hobbyist, so I should definitely be scoring more than 50%!!!

Comment: Question in October 2019 : Is Pluralsight still associated with SO in any way ? I don't find anything "official" related to Pluralsight on the site here. (Excepted meta questions like this one)

Comment: Here are the [questions](https://github.com/tik9/pluralsight-skill-tests/blob/master/javascript.md) taken from 2020, with the wrong ones eliminated obviously.

Comment: @Timo a bunch of these are still wrong lol

Comment: @paco, in Pluralsight if you finish a test you can show the results on the SO career site. Does this help you?

Answer (score 120):

Your experience is not isolated.

In the C++ exam I encountered one question that was outright wrong and a second that was wrong for the latest C++ standard (one answer was right in an old standard, the other 3 were wrong in all versions).

In the C# exam I didn't find any where the "correct" answer was unambiguously wrong, but a handful had ambiguous/misleading wording such that multiple answers should have been accepted.

The post-quiz review was pretty pointless because it didn't provide any explanation or citation of the specification, just the list of answers with the preferred one highlighted.  But there was a "Feedback" link there which allowed reporting bad Q&As.  Since I submitted feedback recently, I have no idea whether they will let me know when they make a decision, or if indeed they read the feedback at all.

Comment: I submitted feedback about a CSS question which incorrectly tried to claim that `border-collapse` removes all borders from a table. That was the day the partnership was announced, and I haven't received any kind of followup about it...

Comment: This... Plus a bunch of C++ answers (did not test other languages) are highly opinion-based.

Comment: Same experience here with C++. I submitted feedback, haven't heard back.

Comment: @animuson I wonder if Pluralsight contracted the exam work out to w3schools...

Answer (score 79):

My experience is not much better. I found most C++ questions low quality or irrelevant (details of C++ stream formatting - why should anyone bother remembering those?).

The questions seem more like a fun quiz about programming language / libraries  quirks than an assessment of skills.

I have tried a few more languages I know a bit (Java, JavaScript, and HTML5) and some more I know almost nothing about (Python and MySQL). In all cases my results were *Proficient*, and the lowest percentile obtained was 41 % in Python. Again my impression was similar: the questions were unable to detect I do not know the technologies.

Add to this the fact they do not support international characters in the user names, but they happily accept them when I write them and produce a garbled results - is the year really 2018?

Overall I find the experience with Pluralsight IQ very unsatisfactory and I am surprised Stack Overflow promotes this or even wants to be associated with this.

Comment: I did fairly well in Python and none of the questions really seemed surprising. The ones I got wrong were obvious as soon as they showed me the answer.

Comment: The C++ ones weren't specific enough, IMO. They assumed C++ _wasn't_ this nuanced, "some platforms do it right, others do it wrong" language.

Answer (score 52):

I failed a question on the JavaScript test (after failing the same two mentioned in your question when picking the same options you picked) that went something like this:

> If you want a live NodeList, which selection method would you use?
>
> - querySelectorAll
> - querySelector
> - query
> - some other one that doesn't actually exist

Now, `querySelectorAll` *does* return a NodeList, but it specifically returns [a **non-live** NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), while `queryselector` returns the first element that matches the selector, so not a NodeList at all, and the last two options don't exist.

I picked one of the ones that didn't exist at random because... what the hell, why not, right? They're all wrong anyways, and I knew they *wanted* me to pick `querySelectorAll` even though doing so would be incorrect.

---

To answer the question in question:

First, a distinction between instances of the `NodeList` interface and instances of the `HTMLCollection` interface.

Both interfaces implement the [collection concept](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-collection):

> A collection is an object that represents a list of nodes. A collection can be either live or static. Unless otherwise stated, a collection must be live.
>   <sub>https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-collection</sub>

However, the NodeList and HTMLCollection interfaces are distinct, even though they are both array-like objects that contain nodes.

Now, for methods that return live instances of the `NodeList` interface (as per the question in question), there are only two of any real note:

- [`Node#childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), and
- [`Document#getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByName)

The first option isn't useful for selecting elements per se, as it is only accessible on instances of the Node interface, and contains all of that elements children. The second option would require the use of a name attribute on the elements, and is only available on instances of the Document interface, so you cannot limit the context, and as such is less than ideal.

Now, moving towards something more useful, the two main selection methods that return live collections in the form of instances of the HTMLCollection interface are:

- [`Element#getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), and
- [`Element#getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Both are much more versatile than the previous methods for a variety of reasons, but still it is very rare to need a live collection of nodes or elements, and there are usually better ways to accomplish the task.

---

I flagged the question in question, as well as the other questions that were incorrect. I have not received a follow-up as of yet.

Comment: For trivia - Note that getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName also return a live NodeList. Although most of the questions were wrong in one way or another.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum they return `HTMLCollection`s, not a `NodeList`, iirc

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) says that an HTMLCollection is returned.

Comment: The "correct" answers to their quiz seem to be based on practices from the ES3 days, even though Pluralsight IQ didn't launch until well into the ES6 era. I have friends who I considered competent junior developers who I hope will **never** know the answers to these questions because they'll never be relevant to them. (I also submitted feedback for several questions without response.)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum [`HTMLCollection`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and [`NodeList`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) are different. They have different capabilities. They don't inherit from each other. They shouldn't be conflated. While they both can be termed a "list of nodes", we should *not* be using the *very specific* name `NodeList` for an `HTMLCollection`, because that causes confusion. A test *certainly* shouldn't specify one when the other is intended (ignoring that the test question still isn't correct if it said `HTMLCollection`).

Comment: @Benjamin [are you sure?](https://jsbin.com/xuxixow/2/edit?js,console) (this snippet—in chrome at least—seems to negate what you're saying).

Answer (score 40):

### More Problematic JavaScript Assessment Items

#### Which of these is NOT a type of Error?

1. `InternalError`
2. `RangeError`
3. `EvalError`
4. `ControlFlowError`

Pluralsight's Answer

> 4. `ControlFlowError`

My Comments:

> This question has an incorrect answer.
>
> `InternalError` is also not defined in browsers or defined the ECMAScript specification, and so should also be a valid answer.

#### Which is the proper way to do prototypal inheritance?

1. ```
   function superclass() {this.stuff="stuff";}
   function subclass() {subclass.prototype = new superclass();}
   ```
2. ```
   function superclass() {this.stuff="stuff";}
   function subclass(superclass) {}
   ```
3. ```
   function superclass() {this.stuff="stuff";}
   function subclass() {}
   subclass.prototype = new superclass();
   ```
4. ```
   function superclass() {this.stuff="stuff";}
   var subclass = new superclass();
   ```

Pluralsight's Answer:

> 3. ```
>    function superclass() {this.stuff="stuff";}
>    function subclass() {}
>    subclass.prototype = new superclass();
>    ```

My Comments:

> None of these answers is correct.
>
> To the extent that this was ever a correct answer, that ended in ES5 (published in 2009) with the addition of `Object.create()`, which is a cleaner way to set up a prototype. But even prior to that, a general solution to setting up prototypical inheritance requires [this dummy constructor dance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7533593/1114), which Pluralsight does not provide as an option.

#### How do you remove an object from the global scope?

1. You can't remove an object from the global scope.
2. Assign it to `null`
3. Memory management will remove it automatically if not referenced.
4. Use the `delete` keyword

Pluralsight's Answer:

> 1. You can't remove an object from the global scope.

My Comments:

> This question has ambiguous/incorrect wording.
>
> The question doesn't ask "how do you remove a binding", or "a variable", or "an assignment" from the global scope, it asks how you remove "an object". And you could indeed detach "an object" from the global scope by "2. Assigning it to `null`" and then "3. Memory management will remove it automatically if not referenced".

### Aside

Pluralsight IQ is roughly linearly-distributed.
Traditional IQ is roughly normally-distributed.

Comment: `InternalError` appears to be defined in Firefox ... but [*only* in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/InternalError).

Comment: Ugh. I'm usually unsympathetic to complaints about "trivia" questions being used to assess programmers (in my experience, interview questions that get slated as "trivia" are usually either everyday basics of a language or algorithm problems that the writer assumes they were supposed to have encountered before and memorised a solution to when in fact other candidates happily solved them in the interview), but the first question here is a classic example of a pointless trivia question. Who the hell knows the complete list of built-in JavaScript errors off the top of their head? And who *cares*?

Answer (score 40):

I just took a whole-bunch-o-tests on Pluralsight. There *is* a feedback button in the bottom left of all questions.

You're not alone. I used that feedback button on about 50% of the questions.

Here were my findings:

- **The JavaScript** test was pretty painfully set in the old ECMAScript 5 days. The question you pointed out is one I just ranted about to a few friends. It even had some obscure terminology I had never heard about (*"Revealing Module Pattern"* I think it was, which was 100% new terminology to me). The few about prototypical inheritance were either misleading or just flat-out wrong/bad practice.
- **The Node.js** test was ridiculous. Passport.js, Sinon, and Mocha are **not** standard Node.js and have **nothing** to do with Node.js proficiency. I've only ever used Mocha and found it stressful that ~40% of the questions had to do with these niche, specific packages.
- **The C++** test used an egregious amount of trickery and had a few "correct" answers that were actually incorrect or undefined behavior based on the standards. Also, some of the answers could have been different if you took compiler optimizations into account (which, if you've ever perused the C++ tag here on Stack Overflow, you should *usually* take into account).
- **The Hacking and Security** test was okay, though very disassembly oriented. No complaints there, really, but it did also have quite a few framework/commercial service related questions that I don't think many people would know (had nothing to do with skill or fundamentals - one of the questions was literally about a specific fuzzing service that fuzzed "Microsof" (misspelled) document formats). As well, it implied that modern string detection utilities couldn't reason about wide characters or even Unicode, which is laughable (I believe the answer they wanted was *"Most tools have problems detecting wide character strings and can only detect ASCII."* which is blatantly false). I also wish they specified which flavor the assembly was in (GAS vs. NASM, etc.) since one of the questions' answers would have been different if the `mov` instruction's operands were reversed (which is the case with certain dialects).
- **Java** was almost exclusively about Java 8 streams. I understand why, and I understand that they are used, but nobody uses streams *that* much. As well, some of the questions were extremely poorly worded and intentionally confusing.
- **The Docker** test was bizarre. A few questions asked about things that made absolutely no sense and that I couldn't even begin to search, because the question was so convoluted and vague and the answers were generic and unhelpful. They kept asking the same thing over and over and implied that several bad practices were in fact good practices.
- **The Python** test was similar to Node.js in that it asked about a *lot* of third-party modules that weren't standard to Python and had nothing to do with the language, standard or surrounding *official* ecosystem. Very frustrating.

What really bothers me are the questions that are *intentionally* tricky just for the sake of throwing the test-taker off. Here I thought I was being tested for proficiency, but some of the questions just wanted to be dicks about test taking specifically. I have mild dyslexia, so the question about `What is the equivalent of (isTrue && isAlsoTrue)` being `!(!isTrue || !isAlsoTrue)` in the not-so-dyslexia-friendly font they used with a super lower timer was incredibly disheartening.

Anyway, I just hit "give feedback" for every little thing I found. All I can do it hope the next person doesn't see those issues :P Maybe, if they're nice enough, they'll pardon some of the ones we got wrong because of the technical inaccuracies of the questions/answers.

Comment: I don't think I remember seeing _any_ third-party modules in the python test. What kind of third-party modules were that "lot"?

Comment: Kudos for the thorough writeup. Just one nitpick: `!(!isTrue || !isAlsoTrue)` is exactly the same as `(isTrue && isAlsoTrue)`, so it's not the inverse.

Comment: What *if* that was the whole idea: turn half-baked product to SO users who (by their nature) will not only complain about bad content but offer improvements?  This way their tests will be crowd-improved.

Comment: @andras Re-take it. You'll get a different set of questions.

Comment: @JustAStudent Thanks, meant to say "equivalent". :)

Comment: @qix I'm aware of that, hence my question.

Comment: Fwiw the revealing module pattern is fairly standard in JavaScript. You probably use it all the time and just dont know that's what it is called.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't use it, personally. At least, not for many years. I know what it is (I've only ever referred to it as an IIFE) but it's not as relevant anymore with Node.js, which is where I spend most of my time. In ~15 years of writing Javascript, I've never come across that term.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Must have gotten a different set than I did. One that stuck out was `python -m CProfile` being the answer to "how do you profile a Python program". Has _nothing_ to do with Python, and since it was one of the earlier questions it threw me off because the other answers indicated there might be a built-in profiler, much like gcc/gcov.

Comment: As far as I know `CProfile` _is_ stdlib, see [#1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), [#2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/cProfile.py).

Comment: Their answer was misspelled, then. `/usr/bin/python: No module named CProfile` - should have been `cProfile`. I'll cede that it's standard but the answer was still technically incorrect.

Comment: @Qix the revealing module pattern is not an IIFE, in essence it is a function that returns an object containing what would be considered the public properties of the interface, instead of being a constructor for an object. That function _could_ be a function expression that is immediately invoked, but that is not a requirement. I personally use the revealing module pattern fairly regularly.

Comment: @TinyGiant Point is, it's not a standard way of referring to that pattern. "Module pattern" is the more correct term. Even then, the concept isn't new to anyone that writes Javascript - you use similar patterns frequently in other ways, anyway. I selected "Module Pattern" instead of "Revealing Module Pattern" but either of them should have been correct.

Comment: @Qix the revealing module pattern is similar to the module pattern in that they both focus on public and private methods, but there are a few differences that would take more space than a comment to explain adequately. As far as Revealing Module Pattern being a standard term, it isn't defined in any of the standards, but no design patterns are as far as I can tell. Revealing Module Pattern _is_ a very common name for this pattern, so that's about as standard as a design pattern name is going to get.

Answer (score 33):

You are not the only one.

I took the test on **Microsoft Office 2016** as I've done a lot of VBA programming and know Access in and out.

But who's an expert in the full range of applications in Office?

**First run** I scored low as I know only little about Delve, Project, and Visio.

One question in Access had no right answer to pick - it suggested *to delete records where the correct method would be to filter them out*.

**Second run** I scored 96% even though no questions were about Access.

This whole setup with PluralSight is below the standard of SO and should be taken under careful reconsideration by the powers that be, until PluralSight manages to bring this to a professional level.

Answer (score 33):

I was also in the JS chat while we were talking about the questions and reviewing the "wrongness" of it all. I was in an overly sassy mood, and decided to reach out to them on twitter.

[image]

Their marketing team at least seems open to discussing the correctness of their assessments, though that doesn't mean all that much.

If you do so feel inclined to reach out they did say to send the assessment of their assessments to `support@pluralsight.com`, though at this point, I think this problem is a bit deeper than a simple email will solve.

It seems like they need to completely redo most of their IQ assessments.

Comment: Why not send them a link to here in a response to their tweet? Also... As far as I can tell the questions are not numbered, and are shown or not shown in random order, so passing on the question numbers is likely to be impossible.

Comment: Yeah I'm surprised they asked you for the question numbers. Do they know how their own product works? Yeesh. Link them to here, they'll get all of the information they need...

Answer (score 13):

I'm one of the developers at Pluralsight who works on this feature. Thank you for all the feedback, we really appreciate it! We're always iterating and trying to improve our tools and the feedback here is helpful.

I wanted to share some background/context on the questions that are presented within an assessment. The questions are created, in large part, by our [course authors](https://www.pluralsight.com/authors) who are practitioners in the relevant language or technology. Each assessment is designed to cover the depth and breadth of knowledge within a skill area. We update and tweak the assessment questions all the time so this discussion is informative. In addition, the question weighting also changes dynamically within each assessment as its being taken, based on how the question is answered, e.g. answering a series of questions incorrectly surface easier questions, correctly answering questions surface more challenging questions, etc.

We have team members who are logging the feedback in this thread and will review it thoroughly, specifically about the questions and the assessments referenced here. Also, as you take an assessment, you can leave feedback directly on the questions within the testing interface (for reference, see image below). So if you come across a question you think needs refinement, please don't hesitate to let us know using that tool!

[image: Providing feedback during the assessment flow]

We love all the feedback that folks are leaving on the questions within the assessments—please keep it coming! We see it, and we're working on addressing it, and we're also working to improving how your feedback gets to us. You can also send comments and feedback to support@pluralsight.com, which will ensure that you hear back from someone on our support team.

Thanks again for your interest in assessments!

Comment: Most of us have mentioned that we did use the feedback feature, but have received no responses.

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, the DOM api is not part of the ECMAScript specification, its a standard library implemented by the browsers. You should have separate assessments for the two.

Comment: @TinyGiant that's great to hear! Right now, we don't have a way to respond to the feedback in the app, yet, or show the status of your feedback, but we do see all of it and we do pass it along to our assessment authors to make the necessary adjustments. Also, thanks for your comment about the DOM API, we are working on releasing additional assessments this year and separating some of these topics is likely to be part of that effort!

Comment: Your service is quite bad at the moment (in terms of questions/answers) - I warmly recommend removing most of these until they are reviewed as you're making a bad name for yourselves - and pluralsight has traditionally had a good name

Comment: Complains and feedbacks kept raining for years but relatively nothing changed.

Comment: @nyedidikeke: It sounds familiar!

Answer (score 11):

I did the Java IQ test out of curiosity. Unfortunately I didn't take screenshots, but I had two main issues:

- It seemed *really* Java8 / stream heavy. Perhaps it was just random chance, and sure, I like streams as well. From the content of the test though it felt very much like a Java 7 -> Java 8 certification update, with a few generic questions thrown in between.
- Some of the questions were ambiguous, wrong, felt "pulled from Google" with no real practical use, or they were of the "why on earth does anyone care?" type. One particular one that stuck out was:

  > What's the difference between an inner class and a nested class?

  The "correct" answer was that nested classes are static, and inner classes are not. I had a few issues with this:

  - Who cares? It feels like a "I pulled this from Google therefore it's relevant" style question, with no real-world use. Anyone referring to these when talking to another developer is going to clarify whether the inner class is static anyway (if that's relevant to the conversation), so I'm not sure how this question tests proficiency in Java at all. It's analogous to the typo-style questions that put a lower case `L` at the end of a number to try to get you to think it's being declared as, say `51` rather than `5`.
  - There was at least a vaguely correct answer (that they're used interchangeably) given as an option, which was then marked wrong.
  - The correct answer is completely wrong - the [Java page on nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) says:

  > Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

  My working theory (which may be wrong of course) is that the question was meant to read "What's the difference between an inner class and a static nested class", but was changed as that would've given the game away... Unfortunately, that change then made the question totally wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Decided to take the Python quiz as I saw some high rep SO users have done.
The very first question turned out to be a massive put-off.
[image]

Issues:

- The first and the third answers are identical.
- How on earth can the student's `name` "*not be edited at a later date*"?

  ```
  >>> class Student:
  ...     def __init__(self, name, gpa=2.0):
  ...         self.name = name
  ...         self.gpa = gpa
  ...     def set_gpa(self, gpa):
  ...         self.gpa = gpa
  ... 
  >>> student = Student('john')
  >>> student.name
  'john'
  >>> student.name = 'mary'
  >>> student.name
  'mary'
  ```

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to be a paid promotion for Pluralsight when it just makes them look like incompetent fools.

Comment: It feels like they just ran a web scraping bot over a dozen of "top X python interview questions" websites, auto-formatted the output and called it a day.

Comment: @ayorgo It's probably cheaper to just pay a bunch of people with no programming experience to copy-paste-format random questions they find on the web than to pay a programmer to write a scrapper and auto-formatter.

Comment: I feel like the question assumes that you're working by rules of some other programming language that has private default members or a coding standard that doesn't allow direct access to members from outside of the class. As in, there isn't a set_name method so you wouldn't have a way to edit it and still adhere to the standard. Still a terrible question, because even with that assumption "A student's name can only be defined when the student is created" is incorrect. It should say "A student's name must be defined when the student is created."