# Include Pluralsight score in the Developer Story PDF

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

Right now, the Pluralsight Skill IQ verification appears in the Developer Story. However, when we save the story as a PDF, the verification is not included in that file. I think it would be reasonable to include it.

Comment: Agreed. If I'm going to use my developer story as a resume replacement then I'm going to print it out, in which case the pluralsight thing loses its meaning

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: Doesn't it lose its meaning anyway since everyone is an Expert?

Comment: But the recruiters don't know that ;-) they see a big number and are impressed by many logos and high numbers.

Comment: Or [remove it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251) - either way.

Comment: @Tschallacka:  If all recruiters were concerned with were big numbers and logos, I may want to look for other places to work, frankly.

Comment: Fwiw, I posted in StackApps about [devstory.fyi](https://stackapps.com/questions/9354/export-so-developer-story-to-devstory-fyi) that will preserve Pluralsight IQ assessments when you import your Developer Story.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion! I've added this request to our internal feedback tracker but at the moment, we have no plans to add this to the PDF export of the dev story.

Answer (score -11):

Open up the PDF in Adobe Illustrator then place a screen shot of the Pluralsight score in the Illustrator file and save as a PDF with the score.

It would take about an hour or 2 to learn and about 5 mins to do.

Basically:

1. file>place image
2. Resize image
3. Export as or Save as