# Generate Pluralsight IQ marks in PDF from Stack Overflow account

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

It has been a long time since this [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363566/include-pluralsight-score-in-the-developer-story-pdf) and it hasn't been implemented yet.

I hope the user is given choices like:

> Print Pluralsight IQ test marks in PDF
>
> - Yes
> - No

Many Community members said that there is no answer to this question but the answer is to increase the upvotes for this feature-request and make it considerable.

Comment: Yes it semi to my question but there are not any considerable answers.

Comment: The duplicate feature-request is tagged with [status-review] which means it's being considered. Given how long ago that was, I'm not too optimistic, but there's not much that can be done about it.

Comment: Dear Community members are that  question have considerable answer. May the solution for this or that question is increase the reputation for any question to make feature request considerable

Comment: @AlASADWAIL - you can give the old feature request a push by upvoting it if you find it helpful and giving a thoughtful response. Unfortunately, cigien's right, nothing else we could do as it is stuck in an "in-review" hell