# Adding a PluralSight assessment to Developer Story

Tags: support, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I'm unable to add any assessment. Looking for an answer, I did try resizing the window and to dig into the HTML code as some users mentioned in various questions/comments. But as I can see, the option to share to SO is simply missing. All older screenshots I've seen show at least three share icons. But in the code there are only two, for LinkedIn and Twitter.

Presumably with Developer Story going out of service by April, 1st, nobody is going to be bothered to change anything. Yet still there is a sliver of hope I can export a shiny resume out of it with all my assessments in a single package.

[image]

Comment: Is the option missing on the SO Developer Story page, or on the PluralSight page?

Comment: @CodyGray, the latter.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. That was what I thought. Unfortunately, I don't think even the Stack Overflow developers (I am not a developer, only a community-elected moderator) have control over the PluralSight site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story)

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, please read the question. That is acknowledged explicitly.

Comment: @CodyGray It is - I think it still answers it though, because it doesn't seem worthwhile to fix a bug in a feature that's going away in a few weeks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

The feature appears to have been intentionally removed by PluralSight as a result of the developer story being removed soon.

Their help center article on Skill IQ [used to mention Stack Overflow](http://web.archive.org/web/20201215184243/https://help.pluralsight.com/help/how-do-i-share-my-skill-iq) as a share option:

[image: Share on Stack Overflow]

But visiting [that page](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/how-do-i-share-my-skill-iq) now, it only mentions sharing on Twitter and LinkedIn. Having even updated the help article to remove reference to Stack Overflow could not be a more clear sign that the feature is no longer available. Not hidden by weird buttons like with past issues - just gone.

That means it is no longer possible to add PluralSight tests to your developer story.

Comment: OK, maybe it's your turn then to remove the option and any mentions of the function?

Comment: That project would be unlikely to get finished before the entire developer story was removed. Our team is very busy ensuring that everything can be safely removed at the end of the month. It's too late to add more tasks to the roadmap at this point. // To ease your pain though, [PluralSight scores were never included in the PDF exports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363566/include-pluralsight-score-in-the-developer-story-pdf), so you wouldn't have gained anything from this feature remaining anyways.