# Page Displays 404 against the Get Skill IQ button

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I was trying to add the "IQ Skills" from Pluralsight via  my Stack Overflow profile but turns up that it is giving 404.

Steps

- Click on "Find out with Pluralsight IQ - take a free assessment now" under the "Developer Story" tab.
  [image]
- Then click on the Get your Skill IQ
  [image]
- This will land you on a page with `404`.
  [image]

Comment: Oh well, it wasn't very accurate anyways. [Lots of the questions were wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363251/4639281)

Comment: You have encountered the first test... :P

Comment: @TinyGiant you broke my heart

Comment: @Shadow that makes me fail the test :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report Muhammad. I just tested this link and I do end up on the correct page.

[image]

Comment: yeah looks like it fixed now, thanks for the prompt.