# Can't link pluralsightIQ to Stack Overflow developer story

Tags: bug, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

I have got PluralSight Skill IQ score

[image]

Which I tried to link in my developer story by clicking on stack overflow icon. But I get redirected to 404 page. Below is the URL in browser on 404 page.

[https://app.pluralsight.com/score/skill-assessment/**undefined**/redirect-to-stack-overflow](https://app.pluralsight.com/score/skill-assessment/undefined/redirect-to-stack-overflow)

There is something **undefined** in URL path parameter, which might be the cause of the issue. Does this have to be reported to pluralsight?

The 404 page occurs after clicking on stack overflow icon on pluralsight, So I assume the issue is from pluralsight! Is there anyone from stack overflow that can confirm this issue?

Comment: This is part of the test, as a JavaScript expert.

Comment: @DavyM This is different issue. the 404 comes when clicking on stack overflow icon on pluralsight.

Comment: @TGrif clearly I am a Novice!

Comment: @Yogesh so... it's a pluralsight issue and not an SO issue?

Comment: @l4mpi that's what I am asking. Just want to be sure if there is nothing from stack overflow that needs to changed!

Comment: @Yogesh It's a bug that happens when you click a link on a third party site, which directs you to an invalid URL on the same third party site. This should always be addressed to the third party site. Just because the link you're clicking is supposed to lead you to SO does not mean SO can do anything here.

Comment: I would [recommend against linking that terrible test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/pluralsight-iq-incorrect-questions-in-test) namely - most of the answers are wrong :D

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, we’ve notified Pluralsight, hopefully a fix is applied soon

Comment: it seems they have fixed it, this works now!