# Not able to see user information in review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Since two days I'm not able to see user information on [the Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) when hovering an avatar.

It looks like something is wrong with the JavaScript, hovering causes a request to an URL like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/undefined/3432678?_=1547110614713`

Comment: Related: [Can't link pluralsightIQ to Stack Overflow developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378820/4642212).

Comment: MSE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322144/being-able-to-see-the-data-on-reviews-when-you-hover-the-mouse-over-a-user-icon

Comment: @Stijn at this point I can probably say that caching saved me from having problems :) ... although I also tried in Safari which is a browser I never use... weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was due to the change in structure: a bit of code was looking for a class that isn't used anymore so that it could pull a data attribute off of it.

Bit of a lesson to be had here on naming: for years we freely mixed classes used for styling, classes used for behavior, and classes used for both. This was convenient, and rather elegant... As long as each page relied mostly on bespoke CSS and JavaScript. It does not scale well at all when trying to create reusable styles *or* behavior however, and led to a situation where it's often hard to know if a styling or markup change will affect (or be affected by) a script without carefully grepping all the relevant scripts.

So more recently, we've adopted the practice of separating these classes: behavioral class-names are prefixed with `js-` and describe the role of the element, while styling classes follow the atomic/component conventions [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks). And now you can see this in action by browsing the markup on the review dashboard...