# Why don't PluralSight IQ scores show up to employers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

This Pluralsight IQ thing doesn't show up on the developer story being sent to employers in my case. I tried downloading a version of the one sent to the employer and nothing regards the Pluralsight IQ where I scored as expert in about five different languages showed up on it. If it isn't going to be showing up, what is it doing to my profile?

Comment: The value of "This pluarlsight IQ thing" is debatable. I wouldn't pay too much attention to it if I were an employer.

Comment: I agree. But why does SO encourage it if it never plans to show it to anyone?

Comment: Because business deals.

Comment: it seems that, for some reason, it is visible only in the [story view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5125586?view=Timeline).

Comment: Their tests appear to be near worthless anyway, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363251/incorrect-questions-in-pluralsight-iq-test

Comment: @CertainPerformance: On the other hand, since you can retry an unlimited number of times (training with fake e-mail addresses), and last I checked they had a very limited amount of questions, you can obtain a 300 score by simply ~~memorizing~~ writing down the answers during your training sessions and using them when finally taking the test with your SO account.

Comment: @CertainPerformance all tests appear to be near worthless for measuring anything except learning by heart...

Comment: You do have a point @9ilsdx9rvj0lo. But why don't SO just scrap it since it seems useless (from my point of view).