# Remove Pluralsight IQ from timeline or header

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, design, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

[image: Part of my Developer Story]

I feel that it's a bad thing that the results of Pluralsight IQ tests are displayed both at the header of my Developer Story and on my timeline. Is this duplication really necessary? It directs user attention away from other information. I think it should be deleted either from the header or the timeline.

EDIT:

In the menu shown after hovering over the gear-icon placed in top-right corner of the "Assessment" timeline entry, there is a "delete" option but choosing it deletes the result altogether, also from the header section of Developer Story.

Comment: Isn’t there an option to delete the timeline entries when clicking on the little gear icon in the top right corner? It seems [there is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363220/4642212).

Comment: The result then disappears from the developer story altogether, also from the header area. I'd like to have it in one place, not two, and not zero :)

Comment: It would probably be better to [edit] your question to mention that.

Comment: At the very least it'd be nice if the timeline items were smaller - I don't think a 5 minute test should occupy the same amount of space as the last 3 years of gainful employment :p

Comment: When I thought about it, I decided to just delete them completely. Pluralsight is stupid and doesn't measure anything of value, I myself could get an "expert" for basically anything without actually having any experience.